# (Apache Mod_Rewrite) Please help to condense my query

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a set of mod_rewrite rules to fulfill the following conditions:

```
1) /aaa  (redirects to) --> /xxx_aaa.php
2) /aaa/                --> /xxx_aaa.php
3) /aaa?w=x&y=z         --> /xxx_aaa.php?w=x&y=z
3) /aaa/?y=z            --> /xxx_aaa.php?y=z
4) /aaa/bbb/            --> /xxx_aaa_bbb.php
5) /aaa/bbb/ccc/        --> /xxx_aaa_bbb_ccc.php
6) /aaa/bbb/cc12-34cc   --> /xxx_aaa_bbb_cc12-34cc.php
7) /aaa/bbb/ccc/?y=z    --> /xxx_aaa_bbb_ccc?y=z.php
```

The above list isn't exhaustive, but it gives you an idea of all the possible permutations I am aiming to cover. Namely, these are:

1) Up to three subdirectory levels
2) Works whether closing forward slash is present or not
3) Pass GET query strings, if present

This is that I use at the moment:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)$ /xxx_$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/$ /xxx_$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/\?([0-9a-zA-Z\-=&]+)$ /xxx_$1.php?$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)$ /xxx_$1_$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/$ /xxx_$1_$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/\?([0-9a-zA-Z\-=&]+)$ /xxx_$1_$2.php?$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)$ /xxx_$1_$2_$3.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/$ /xxx_$1_$2_$3.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/\?([0-9a-zA-Z\-=&]+)$ /xxx_$1_$2_$3.php?$4 [L]
```

And it seems to work just fine.

But I can't help but think that there must be a much more elegant way of doing it - perhaps even condensing all the above into one single line.

Any ideas? Any help much appreciated, thanks. :)

Comment: For the sake of performance, it might be best just keeping things as they are, but I am curious as to how it could be done. A one-liner would be awesome!

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Z\-]+)/?$ /xxx_$1.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Z\-]+)/([0-9A-Z\-]+)/?$ /xxx_$1_$2.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Z\-]+)/([0-9A-Z\-]+)/([0-9A-Z\-]+)/?$ /xxx_$1_$2_$3.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

NC = non case so A-Z = a-z

QSA = query string append = ?w=x&y=z will be set (for example $_GET['w'] in PHP)

Comment: Just wondering if it would be possible using another group to combine $1 $2 $3.. like ^(([0-9A-Z\-]+)/)+?$ ..

Comment: @NitWit good idea but that will require to parse all the "subfolder" in 1 file instead of here having a specific file for each folder